# Capybara is sending HTML format on request instead of JS on RSpec tests (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

The feature works perfectly on the browser, however on the tests when Capybara clicks the submit button the request is processed as an HTML:

```
Processing by SearchController#index as HTML
```

Instead of:

```
Processing by SearchController#index as JS
```

This is my form on the view:

```
<%= form_with url: search_index_path, local: false, id: 'search-organization', method: :get do |f| %>
```

I'm using Rspec, capybara and poltergeist.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons for this

1. You aren't actually using the poltergeist driver for the given test, but are instead using rack_test which doesn't process JS
2. You are using some ES 5.1+ feature/methods in your JS and not completely transpiling it to ES 5.  Poltergeist uses PhantomJS which currently (v 2.1.1) only supports up to ES 5.  You can make sure you turn on the `js_errors: true` option in the Poltergeist driver (which will show errors about non-existent methods, etc), however if you use some newer features (let, const, etc) PhantomJS will sometimes not raise an error and instead just silently ignore all the JS in the given file.

Comment: On (1): I've tested it is poltergeist
On (2): I could not get any errors. I also could not find any errors on production.

Other info:
I've upgraded from rails 5 to rails 5.1, could this be an upgrade issue?

Comment: @AdemarTutor On (2) - as I mentioned it's possible for PhantomJS not to raise an error, and just ignore the JS, if you have any code using ES6 features (like let, const, etc.) - and that wouldn't raise any errors in production since the browser you would be using would support newer JS features.  Try running the tests using the selenium driver and see if they work then.  If they do that would pretty much guarantee you have ES6 code that's not being transpiled/polyfilled to ES5